# How to access props to external js file

Tags: reactjs

The answers to this type of scenario I've seen all involved a class component. 
I have a functional component in React.

```
const MyComponent = props => {
// all my code
// here I can execute props.firebase.someother stuff
}
```

As the above says I have a props.firebase which is linked to a firebase context.  This allows me to call firebase.  It works and it's all good.
To keep my code a little cleaner I'd like to do some of these calls in an external js file.

I'd like to do:

```
import { myMethod } from "./helpers/allcalls.js";

In my allcalls.js
export function setRecords(data) {
props.firebase.makecall.set(data)
}

const MyComponent = props => {
// all my code
// here I can execute props.firebase.someother stuff
 setRecords(someDataFromState)
}
```

In the above props is undefined.
In a class I would bind that to (this) and then use this.props.firebase in the external js.  I can't figure out how to do it in a functional component thou.
Any ideas?

Comment: what if you pass the props as param for your external function  and call it there?

Comment: props is undefined because you're not passing a parameter called props to that function

Comment: Where are you calling props ? The code sample you've posted is a bit confusing, Where is the `props` in the `allcalls.js` being called from?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly props can be passed to any other method but needs to go as a parameter correct?  If it's not passed specifically even thou the method is executed in the "parent" method it won't work?  @AlexW

Comment: @FabricioG yes, props is an object and thus can be passed, you can pass it to any function

Comment: Let's know if it works

Comment: Stateless components (i.e. functional / non-class components) receive props as a parameter passed to the function.  If you want to use state in stateless / functional components you should use the `useState` hook introduced in React 16.8.

Answer (score 0):

Per this great help: @AlexW & @Claeusdev

Props is an object and can be passed to any outside method.

```
    import { myMethod } from "./helpers/allcalls.js";

const MyComponent = props => {
// all my code
// here I can execute props.firebase.someother stuff
 setRecords(props, someDataFromState)
}
```

In my allcalls.js

```
export function setRecords(data) {
props.firebase.makecall.set(data)
}
```

The above code is incomplete, it should be assumed props and all other import React, etc would be included.